GPG: copied ~/.gnupg to a new computer but got "no secret key"
I recently attempted to migrate my GPG keyring to a new computer through the recommended method of simply copying the ~/.gnupg folder. However, possibly due to GPG version differences or missing dependencies, I failed to decrypt anything on my new laptop with the following error:
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

Additionally, both gpg --list-keys and gpg --list-secret-keys return no output. GPG returns the error instantly instead of waiting for a few seconds which would be expected if pinentry was missing or misconfigured.
I have already tried the following recommendations from the many threads on this error message with no success:

Restart gpg-agent
Restart my computer
Ensure pinentry is installed
Configure GPG to use pinentry-tty
Set GPG_TTY=$(tty)
Set DISPLAY=""
Use various arcane GPG flags


The solution was the conjunction of the following two changes, and possibly the effects of some of the ones that I had already tried:

Configure gpg-agent with the explicit location of the pinentry-tty executable, which was different from what it expected since I am using Nix OS.
Edit the .gnupg/common.conf file to remove its only line, which read use-keyboxd.

.gnupg/common.conf had been added by the new version of gpg to my copied .gnupg directory, which I discovered after comparing it with the original directory on my old laptop. I have no idea what it does.
I acknowledge that I am pretty ignorant in this area. I hope that this helps anyone who has had the same issue, and please comment if you know what is going on or if I have committed any sins that should be warned against.

I had the same problem, no output on gpg --list-keys. Removed use-keyboxd from common.conf, now --list-keys shows my keys.
